# Using integration to prove convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

here's my question:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ continuous and increasing.

Prove that:
$\sum f(e^{-n})$ and $\sum \dfrac 1 n f\left(\dfrac 1 n \right)$ are both convergent or divergent.

p.s. A tip says I could try to use integration, but I don't know how...

Thans a lot~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to apply the *Integral Test* for convergence of series to both of them. Interestingly enough, after substitutions both integrals turn into the same one!

For the first series $\sum f(e^{-n})$, consider the function $h(x)=f(e^{-x})$ on $x\in[0,+\infty)$. Because of the given conditions on $f$, $h$ is positive, continuous, and decreasing, so the Integral Test applies, and then given series converges or diverges together with the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty}h(x)\,dx=\int_0^{+\infty}f(e^{-x})\,dx$. Now let's substitute $t=e^{-x}$; then $x=-\ln t$ and $dx=-\frac{1}{t}dt$. So the integral becomes
$$\int_0^{+\infty} h(x)\,dx=\int_0^{+\infty} f(e^{-x})\,dx=\int_1^0 f(t)\cdot\frac{-1}{t}\,dt=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t}f(t)\,dt,$$
improper at $t=0$.

For the second series $\sum \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{1}{n})$, consider the function $g(x)=f(\frac{1}{n})$ on $x\in(0,+\infty)$. Because of the given conditions on $f$, $g$ is positive, continuous, and decreasing, so the Integral Test applies, and then given series converges or diverges together with the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty}g(x)\,dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x}f(\frac{1}{x})\,dx$. Now let's substitute $t=\frac{1}{x}$; then $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and $dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$. So the integral becomes
$$\int_0^{+\infty} g(x)\,dx=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,dx=\int_1^0 tf(t)\cdot\frac{-1}{t^2}\,dt=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t}f(t)\,dt,$$
improper at $t=0$.

So both series converge or diverge together with the same improper integral.